# How to get user account unique id (GUID) on Windows?

Tags: winapi, guid, uniqueidentifier

I would like to obtain a unique identifier (GUID not SID) of Windows account which my application is currently running on. I tried with `GetUserNameEx` with `NameUniqueId` as format. It works well on some machines but fails with `ERROR_NONE_MAPPED` on others (which seems to be a known problem):

[How do you read the user's display (first and last) name on all versions of Windows reliably?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686201/how-do-you-read-the-users-display-first-and-last-name-on-all-versions-of-wind)

[Getting the full-name of the current user, returns an empty string (C#/C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990340/getting-the-full-name-of-the-current-user-returns-an-empty-string-c-c)

Above mentioned questions concentrate on user name but doesn't answer how to obtain user account GUID.

Comment: If an account does not have a mapped guid, it does not have a guid.  Why do you need the guid?

Comment: @KenWhite indeed you're right. It was my misinterpretation of the documentation plus some misleading information on different forums. Please write this as an answer so that I can close this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [GetUserNameEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that `ERROR_NONE_MAPPED` means the user name is not available in the specified format. The function cannot return what does not exist; if there is no user account GUID, then the function can't return one.

> **ERROR_NONE_MAPPED**    The user name is not available in the specified format.

The same documentation (in the *Parameters* section, under `NameFormat [in]`) says (in part):

> If the user account is not in a domain, only `NameSamCompatible` is supported.

So the answer to your question is to try to get the GUID using `NameUniqueID`, and if that returns `ERROR_NONE_MAPPED` fall back to using `NameSamCompatible`, which is available in all cases.

Comment: IIRC, the GUID is an LDAP thing, which is why it is only applicable to Active Directory accounts.